# Как вызвать VirtualMachineError(); на Java

Tags: java

Не могу нигде найти как вызвать ошибку JVM,
почему этот код не компилируется?

`throw new VirtualMachineError();`

если нет возможности  прямо вызвать эту ошибку напишите если можно короткий код который приводит к этой ошибке и компилируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если почитать документацию https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/VirtualMachineError.html

```
public abstract class VirtualMachineError
extends Error
Thrown to indicate that the Java Virtual Machine is broken or has run out of resources necessary for it to continue operating.
```

что дословно переводится Брошенный, чтобы указать, что виртуальная машина Java сломана или у нее закончились ресурсы, необходимые для продолжения работы.

экземпляр абстрактного класса мы создать не можем, но можем наследоваться

```
class MyEx extends VirtualMachineError {
    public MyEx(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        throw new MyEx("VirtualMachineError");
    }
}
```

вывод:
Exception in thread "main" MyEx: VirtualMachineError

Comment: даже не подумал что этот класс может быть абстрактным, и не смотрел его, он же крайний в ветке и не имеет наследников

Comment: @tka в ide `throw new VirtualMachineError();` тебе подчёркивает  и пишет `'VirtualMachineError' is abstract; cannot be instantiated`

Comment: так что если учишься в блокноте, кидай дурное